# Unable to add Spring Artifact IDs to project

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

Can anyone tell me why I am unable to add the following dependencies to my pom.xml file?

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The moment I add the spring-web dependency the first error is displayed:

Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-web:jar4.3.6.RELEASE.

The first two dependencies added just fine. No errors.

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my entire pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.we.springtest</groupId>
  <artifactId>springtest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <!-- Shared version number properties -->
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <!--Spring Framework-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
      
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
     </dependency>
    -->
  <build>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Maven project in Eclipse do :

- Right click on the project > Maven > Update Project

If it's a Java Project in Eclipse do :

- `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -U` in your console

If it doesn't work, go in your Maven Repository and delete the folder `org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.6.RELEASE`

Comment: Didn't work. I even tried removing the failed downloads. Still nothing. When I try running mvn clean from the console it says it cannot transfer the artifact ID.

Comment: The issue I just listed was because I was running that from a network location. I am able to run mvn clean locally and receive no errors however, once I bring in the spring-webmvc the build fails. It says it cannot find the spring-webmvc artifact. Is it possible that my firewall could be blocking these two dependencies? Because that doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Also deleted the folders as you suggested, it still fails spring-webmvc. Folder also gets re-created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to download them and install them manually. Just would have been nice to use maven.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Eclipse and reinstalled it. I also removed everything that was referencing Eclipse in my local profile. I'm able to add the dependencies. Not the best resolution but something in their was causing an issue.